# Handling multiple mysql databases using a web service

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am using REST web service for my online application developed in PHP and MySql Database.

I have 2 MySql databases with different name called DB1 and DB2.
Both DB1 and DB2 contains the same table structure and same table names.

My service decides which database to use when a request is made.
The portal is used worilwide and serves thousands of requests.

I am little worried coz there are 2 different database but have tables with same names.

Would this cause any mess??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not at all.
If you programm somewhat oop everything will stay inside it's own container/connection.

I use multiple databases all the time, they never leave there classes/containers. Therefor they will never touch eachother.
And according to what you are saying you never use both connections at the same time so you basicly wont ever notice it's there ^^

The only way there would be a mess if you need both datases synced.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. but what if I dont close the database connection after doing operation on it. Do I need to close the DB1 database connections before connecting to DB2 database and vice versa?

Comment: no that is not needed they are 2 sepperate conenctions if you put them in 2 differnet varaibles they are completely seppeared. How ever allways close you connections! they can buy out and cause that connection to get stuck for 2 min(page will keep laoding) rare bug but it happends. This however has nothing to do with the amount of connections you make.